# Can't position absolute Div even though parents are relative

Tags: html, css

For some reason when I put on the id "enterGame" `position: absolute` div disappears.  Even if I add to body or html tag `position: relative` I still can't see the div.

Relevant code:

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue, pink);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: default;
}

#enterGame {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div id="enterGame"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I do see the white div. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @fphilipe also if you put a property of position: absolute ?

Comment: I see no absolute or relative positioning in your code. Maybe you don't see it because it does not have content or is hidden behind other element (z-index)

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you add `position: absolute` it disappears because it doesn't have a width. Try setting `width: 100vw` and it appears again.

Answer (score 0):

when you add absolute you need to give the div some width

```css
html {
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue , pink);
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

* {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1vw;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: default;
}

#enterGame {
    height: 50vh;
    width:200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="enterGame"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answers, I'll give you **the tool** to deal with these kinds of problems, know it and you'll be able to solve the problem better **yourself** in the future, which is the **Dev Tool**- **Inspector**.

---

Now try inspecting the DOM, as you can see in the image below with the inspector *(`F12`/`Ctrl+Shift+I` on Windows/Linux)*, it shows that the element `#enterGame` has the size of `0x173.846`, then => either its `height` or `width` is 0.

[image]

If you ain't already know which number is `width`, which is `height` then you can try inspecting the neighbor `h1`, you'll see that it's `375x21`, so it's obvious that `375` is the width, then => the `#endterGame` disappears is because it doesn't have the `width`. Now try adding `width: 100%` (like the answers above said) will solve the problem.
[image]

```css
html {
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(lightblue , pink);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

* {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1vw;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: default;
}

#enterGame {
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="enterGame"></div>
</body>
```